# Make mandatory group in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

My string requirement is m+/-n.n. it will accept string m plus(+) or minus(-) any integer or decimal number. i.e,  m+1, m+.1, n+0.1, m+1.1, similar with minus(-) sign.

I tried with regex pattern `'^(?:m|M)[+-](\\d{1,})?(\\.\\d{1,0})?$'`

Here the problem is it is also accepting 'm+' or 'm-', which should not be. Here, after [+-] there are two groups, both are individually optional, which is required to support .1, 0.1, 1, 1.1. Want to convert those two groups into one group and make it mandatory.

Comment: You can get a single capturing group `[Mm][+-](\d*\.?\d+)` it will match the `M+` or `m+` but it is not part of the group and the group is not optional. https://regex101.com/r/hUGUHq/1

Comment: There should be only 1 mandatory group right which will match the values `1.1` `.1` etc?

Comment: If it is possible then why not?

Comment: I added a solution which uses a mandatory single capturing group. Reading the question, I assumed that was the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to add a lookahead before the two groups:

```
^(?:m|M)[+-](?=[\d.])(\d+)?(\.\d+)?$
```

Here I added `(?=[\d.])`, which asserts that there must be either a `.` or a `\d` after the `[+-]`, but does not consume it, as it should be consumed by the optional groups after the lookahead.

#### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WfMIp1/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could match either M or m and + or - using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Then capture in group 1 matching 0+ digits, an optional dot and 1+ digits.

This way there is a single capturing group, which is not optional so a string like `m-` would not match on its own.

```
^[Mm][+-](\d*\.?\d+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[Mm]` Match either M or m
- `[+-]` Match either + or -
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d*\.?\d+` Match 0+ digits, optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3jdju2/1)

**Note** that in the example, this `\d{1,0}` is not valid.